# The inner product in Cartan matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $\Delta=\{e_i-e_{i+1} \}_{i=1}^{i=n}$ be a simple root system of $sl(n,\mathbb C)$, where  $e_i\in H^*$ be such that $e_i(X)=$ the $i^{th}$ entry of $X$, and $H\leq sl(n,\mathbb C)$ consists of diagonal entries.

Now by definition Cartan matrix is given by  $$A_{i,j}:= \frac{2\langle\alpha_i,\alpha_j\rangle}{\langle\alpha_i,\alpha_i\rangle}$$
But I don't understand what is the inner product $\langle,\rangle$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner product is as simple as it gets:
$$\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$$
In general the inner product is given by the Killing form.

Comment: How can I prove that $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$ by using the definition of the inner product in $\Delta$ which is $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle:=\kappa (t_\alpha,t_\beta)$?

Comment: @Ronald try using the definition to see if you can do it for $n=2$.